# How to create a horizontal dashed arrow for Squarespace

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm just needing some HTML and CSS to create a normal dashed arrow in Squarespace.
[image: Bold dashed arrow]

I would like to customise the colour to #034472 and have similar style to the pic, pointing right, if possible.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Answer (score 1):

```css
 span {
      content: "\21E0";
      font-size: 100px;
      color: #034472;
    }
```

```html
<span style="color: #034472; font-size: 100px;">&#8672;</span>
```